# create a sequence of two modifiers for two sprite andengine

Tags: android, andengine, modifier

I am trying to create two sprites and applying a RotationAtModifier at each. I want to be able to run both in a sequence, meaning Modifier1 on Sprite1 and after that Modifier2 on Sprite2. Is there any way to achieve that. I tried sequence and loop modifiers but i think they can be used for applying multiple modifiers for a single sprite. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
final RotationAtModifier rotMod1 = new RotationAtModifier(50, 0, 90, 830, 150){

@Override
protected void onModifierStarted(IEntity pItem) {
    getEngine().runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        if(! Sprite1.isVisible()){
            Sprite1.setVisible(true);       
        }}
    });
}

@Override
protected void onModifierFinished(IEntity pItem) {
    getEngine().runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        Sprite1.setVisible(false);  

        }
    });
}
};
RotationAtModifier rotMod = new RotationAtModifier(50, 0, 90, 830, 150){

@Override
protected void onModifierStarted(IEntity pItem) {
    getEngine().runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        if(! Sprite2.isVisible()){
            Sprite2.setVisible(true);       
        }}
    });
}

@Override
protected void onModifierFinished(IEntity pItem) {
    getEngine().runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
            Sprite2.setVisible(false);
            Sprite1.registerEntityModifier(rotMod1);
        }
    });
}
};

mScorpius.registerEntityModifier(rotMod);
```

Comment: You are right about "single sprite can contain multiple modifier". But if you want sequence in animation one after another. Then you have to create two methods for each modifier. One call modifier finish method call another method and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

set Modifier2 on Sprite2 in the `onModifierFinishedBlock` of Modifier1